# How to Handle Exception that occur in static resource?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have problem with spring mvc exception handling in static resource.

this is my webInitializer class

```
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}

protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class};
}

protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected FrameworkServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    return dispatcherServlet;
}
```

and webConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "main.spittr.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
            new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resource/");

}
}
```

and ExceptionHandler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public String notFoundPage404() {
    return "error/404";
}
}
```

every thing work good when page not found exception thrown and my custom 404 show up but when a request comes for wrong static resource like http://localhost:8080/resource/3 ,exception handler not working and result page like this :

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQLIj.png)

How to enable exception handler for static resource?
sorry for bad english.